# Setting up a remote environment that runs on a SLURM compute node

Tags: cluster-computing, jobs, slurm, hpc

I'm trying to set up a remote environment (PyCharm preferred, VSCode also okay) so I can run and debug all my experiments on a compute node in a SLURM-managed cluster. The issue is that I have to run `srun` from a login node (that I SSH into) in order to reserve resources and connect. Most times I do this I also end up on a different machine. What I'd like is to be able to connect once via `ssh` and `srun`, and then tunnel everything to this new hardware limited job context.

Some things I've tried:

- Run an interactive `bash` session using `srun`, then attaching a job to that jobid using [`sattach`](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sattach.html). I think this will always just wait until the bash session has ended before being able to run the command supplied with `sattach`.
- `ssh`ing into a node already running my job. (Due to what I think is `pam_slurm_adopt`, I can't `ssh` into any node, but I *can* `ssh` into one where my job is already running. This works, but gives me access to all GPUs and all hardware on the machine and causes chaos once someone else joins the same node reserving only one or two GPUs.
- Everything in this thread https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1722

An idea I had was to `srun` `tmux` instead of `bash` and then forward ports and attach to that `tmux` session somehow on connection via SSH to the login node, but I'm not entirely sure how that would work.

Comment: In short, you want to port-forward the compute node to your local machine? I am doing this on a daily basis, if that is what you want to do.

Comment: Yes! Are you able to do this while respecting the hardware allocated to your instance of `srun` (only using the correct amount of CPU/memory/GPUs)?

Comment: yes. you need to start a server on a port and forward that port to your local PC. Ideally, I use a Jupyter lab server. I open this forwarded port on VS code. You can use python scripts as well as ipynb files in jupyter server.  if you allocate 1 GPU, than you will be able to use only 1 GPU, if that is what you mean.

Comment: But this doesn't allow you to run your VSCode SSH environment, right? Can I tunnel an SSH connection by just opening ports?

Comment: Do you mean you want to run a local environment on the cluster? I do not think that is possible. HPCs are not supposed to work like this.
You can open a port with SSH forwarding, but there is no receiver in the HPC cluster. Why don't you copy your `requirements.txt` and create a new env on the HPC cluster? Also, you can create an Apptainer image since Docker doesn't work with HPCs.

Comment: I know this isn't supposed to work, but it is really useful to have a GPU during debugging, and the HPC management doesn't mind if I take up a single GPU and a modest amount of memory doing so. I already have my environments set up, the issue is just that I'm not able to set SSH Python interpreters in PyCharm/VSCode that will run on the compute node.

Comment: you can't. I even modify my code for hours with GPU and nobody cares.  But you need to have your environment on the cluster. If your environment is really complicated, then I suggest going for Apptainer containers. Since you can port forward the whole OS inside the Apptainer image.